inserting in two related tables using laravel 11 with one request
i worked with angular for front end and and i want to perform CRUD with laravel
i have two tables users and students, students table have a foreign key referencing to users table.
i want to insert the data that comes from one form, i tried this:

student model

        <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Etudiant extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'students';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idStudent';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        'dateNaissance',
        'filier',
        'niveauEtude',
        'cne',
        'specialite'
    ];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\User::class);
    }
    use HasFactory;
}


user model

    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Utilisateur extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idUser';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        'nom',
        'prenom',
        'password',
        'email',
        'numTel'
    ];

    public function student(){
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Student::class);
    }

    use HasFactory;
}


Student Cotroller

    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Users;
use App\Models\Student;

class StudentController extends Controller
{

    protected $student;
    protected $user;
    protected $studentData;
    protected $userData;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->student = new Student();
        $this->user = new Utilisateur();
    }


    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */

    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $studentData = array_diff_key($request->all(), array(['nom', 'prenom', 'password', 'email', 'numTel']));
        $userData = array_diff_key($request->all(), array(["dateNaissance", "filier", "niveauEtude", "cne", "specialite"]));

        $this->user->student()->create($userData);
        $this->student->user()->create($studentData);

        return [];
    }}


Error i get

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'utilisateur_idUser' in 'field list' (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into etudiant (dateNaissance, filier, niveauEtude, cne, specialite, utilisateur_idUser) values (12/12/12, mip, bac+3, m130118922, MA, ?))

As you're using the relationship $this->user->student(), utilisateur_idUser is the auto-generated column name to search for the relation between the student and the user, this is, your students table need to have a column to refer to the user and by default Laravel expects it to be named after the parent model + _ + parent primary key. If the name of your foreign key in the students table is different, you need to explicitly define it when declaring your relationship:
    public function student(){
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Student::class, 'fk_in_students_table_referring_to_the_users_table');
    }

Now, to accomplish what you want, you need first to create your user, e.g.: $this->user->fill(...)->save(); and then use your user to create the related student, e.g.: $this->user->students()->create(...);
Also, if your user only need to have one student linked, the proper relationship would be ->hasOne() instead ->hasMany()
To filter only a subset of values from an associative array you can use Arr::only($request->all(), ['key1', ...])
